# Django 1.5.4 - sqlite datetime - model.datetimeField returns None

Tags: django, sqlite, datetime, django-models

I'm having issues with retrieving datetime columns.  Instead of returning the correct datetime,  model.field returns None.

The model, CustomerPeriod is defined as below:

```
class CustomerPeriod(models.Model):
    id = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, decimal_places=0, max_digits=22)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

As as example, the table is populated as below:

```
customer_period = CustomerPeriod()
customer_period.id = Decimal('1118632')
customer_period.customer_id = 1
customer_period.begin_date = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 5, 0)
customer_period.end_date = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 6, 0)

customer_period.save()
```

Now, attempting to get the value of the begin_date field, null is returned instead of the expected date, as populated above.

`CustomerPeriod.objects.all()[0].begin_date`

returns None???!

Additionally, I can see the expected data in a database browser.

Thanks in advance for help.

Versions:

- Sqlite3  3.7.12
- Python 2.7.4
- Django 1.5.4

Stewart

Comment: What does `CustomerPeriod.objects.get(id=1).begin_date` give you ?

Comment: CustomerPeriod.objects.get(id=1).begin_date returns None.

Comment: Hum, thats strange, I can't reproduce your problem. Is it still appearing when the field is populated with an automated datitime like `datetime.datetime.now()` ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't data in the table already? Maybe the object with id=1 has no date value.

Comment: I can see the data in database browser - all is as expected.

Comment: Using datetime.datetime.now() to populate the model still return None.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is still pending, but just dealt with this issue myself. You need to ensure that the column type of the sqlite db is datetime. if it is just date than it returns None when you try to pull it out with python. Drop that table if it is and re-sync.

Comment: Well found - it bugged me too!